# Problem compiling driver for usb31000sw usb-ethernet adapter

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, usb, compiling

I'm trying to build a driver for the Startech USB31000SW. A linux driver is included but it has to be compiled and installed. When running `make` I get the following errors:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-52-generic-pae/build SUBDIRS=/home/lars/Hämtningar/usbnet/Linux/Kernel 2.6.x_3.x modules
make[1]: Går till katalogen "/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-52-generic-pae"
make[1]: *** Ingen regel för att skapa målet "2.6.x_3.x".  Stannar. 
make[1]: Lämnar katalogen "/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-52-generic-pae"
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

The third line translates to: No rule to create target

According to the read me file, the kernel source is needed, so I installed it from Synaptic.

This is the makefile:

```
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
TARGET  = ax88179_178a
OBJS    = ax88179_178a.o
MDIR    = drivers/net/usb
KDIR    = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
SUBLEVEL= $(shell uname -r | cut -d '.' -f 3 | cut -d '.' -f 1 | cut -d '-' -f 1 | cut -d '_' -f 1)
USBNET  = $(shell find $(KDIR)/include/linux/usb/* -name usbnet.h)

ifneq (,$(filter $(SUBLEVEL),14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21))
MDIR = drivers/usb/net
#USBNET = $(shell find $(KDIR)/$(MDIR)/* -name usbnet.h)
endif

#ifneq (,$(filter $(SUBLEVEL),21 22 23 24))
#USBNET = $(shell find $(KDIR)/$(MDIR)/* -name usbnet.h)
#endif

#$(if $(USBNET),,$(error $(KDIR)/$(MDIR)/usbnet.h not found. please refer to readme file for the detailed description))

EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXPORT_SYMTAB
PWD = $(shell pwd)
DEST = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/kernel/$(MDIR)

obj-m      := $(TARGET).o

default:
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

$(TARGET).o: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LD_RFLAG) -r -o $@ $(OBJS)
pw
install:
    su -c "cp -v $(TARGET).ko $(DEST) && /sbin/depmod -a"

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean

.PHONY: modules clean

-include $(KDIR)/Rules.make
```

Any ideas would be welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have spaces in your directory names in this build directory tree. When you remove the space in the directory name `/home/lars/Hämtningar/usbnet/Linux/Kernel 2.6.x_3.x` (the space between "Kernel" and "2.6.x_3.x") it should work.

It's because the "make" command doesn't recognise the option "2.6.x_3.x". "Make" has to make (compile) "modules", but it tries to make "2.6.x_3.x" because of the spaces in the command.

Answer (score 0):

From Synaptic, please install linux-headers-generic and build-essential and try again. If it still won't compile, please provide a link to the driver so we may toubleshoot further. Also, post:

```
lsusb
```